# storing data on a buffer on c++

Tags: c++, buffer, uint32-t

I have a simple function on c++ which takes 2 arguments:

```
read(uint32_t *buffer, uint32_t num_words){
    ...
}
```

When I try to call it I get an error because the arguments I pass are probably wrong `unsigned long*, unsigned long`:

```
uint32_t addr = 5;
uint32_t buf[5];
read(buf,addr);
```

I'm not sure why this is wrong.
Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on what sort of platform you are running the program on, say in certain systems `int` is 32 bit, so you don't need `unsigned long`, try using `unsigned int`.

Comment: It's on an embedded system using freeRTOS, `int` doesn't work either, I'm puzzled

Comment: *What* errors do you get? Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error log. Also, some operating systems might already have a `read` system call, you sure it's not the case here?

Comment: FreeRTOS can be installed on both 16 and 32 bit processors. Why do you think the error is "probably" because of the inconsistent data type? what exactly is the error.

Comment: The error is: `undefined reference to Storage::readFlash(unsigned long*, unsigned long)`. I have now realised that the function was missing the namespace `Storage::`

Comment: Guess the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because the compiler is not able to convert pointer to const pointer(that is array variable). Change the prototype of of read to read(uint32_t buffer [], uint32_t num_words)..
This will work.